# Codeigniter, blank page

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter

I know there is a lot of answers about this issue but i couldn't find a solution:

I use CI 2.1.3 and mssql DB connector +Freetds on RHEL 6 and I always have a blank page on controllers that use DB connection

**When i try with a simple PHP script(whithout CI) and same parameters, it works.**

Here is my CI environnement:

```
ini_set("display_errors", "on");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set ("error_log "," logs/php.log");
```

Autoload configuration : With "database" or whithout : blank page !

config/database.php:

```
$active_group = 'DEV';
$active_record = TRUE;


$db['DEV']['hostname'] = 'XXXX\\XXXXXX';
$db['DEV']['database'] = 'XXXXX';
$db['DEV']['username'] = 'XXXXX';
$db['DEV']['password'] = 'XXXXXXXXX';
$db['DEV']['dbdriver'] = 'mssql';
$db['DEV']['dbprefix'] = 'XXXXXX';
$db['DEV']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['DEV']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['DEV']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['DEV']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['DEV']['char_set'] = 'ANSI';
$db['DEV']['dbcollat'] = 'latin1_swedish_ci';
$db['DEV']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['DEV']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['DEV']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

There is no log (chmod is 777)

Need some help on this... Thanks

Comment: have you set these parameters in config/database.php
$active_group = 'DEV';
$active_record = TRUE;

Comment: Yes, i'ts already set

Comment: Have you added database library in controller or in config/autoload.php?